# Question about tangent vector and tangent space of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $S$  be a manifold of dimension $n$.Let $\phi: S\to\Bbb{R^n}$ be a homeomorphism which is a coordinate system for $S$.That is for $p\in S$ we have $\phi(p)=[\xi^1,...,\xi^n]$ be the coordinate of the point $p\in S$.

Let $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function and $\gamma:R\to S$ be a curve then the tangent vector at a point $p=\gamma(a)$ is defined as $$\frac{d \gamma}{dt}=\frac{d(f\circ \gamma(t))}{dt}$$ at $t=a.$

Okay, so my question is suppose we have a manifold $S=\mathbb{S^1}$=$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}/x^2+y^2=1\}$ and let I have to calculate the tangent vector at point $p=(0,1)$ then how can I apply the above definition to find it. I mean what will be my $f$ and $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that $f$ is arbitary, and I've constructed a family $\gamma_s$ in my answer below.

Let me first answer this question using the standard embedding of $S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, let me produce for you a set of curves $\gamma_s:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ such that for any $s\in  T_{(0,1)}S^1\cong  \mathbb{R}\times 0$, we have
$$\frac{d\gamma_s}{d\theta}\bigg\vert_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2s}}=-s.$$
This negative jumps out because of the insistence to parameterize the circle counterclockwise: it's a purely a matter of cosmetics. I will show the tangent vectors at $p$ is in 1-1 correspondence with the following curves: $\gamma_s(\theta):=(\cos(s\theta),\sin(s\theta))$.

By Pythagoren theorem, the image of these curves lie on $S^1$. By construction, $\gamma_s(\frac{\pi}{2s})=(\cos(s\frac{\pi}{2s}),\sin(s\frac{\pi}{2s}))=(0,1)$. Furthermore,
$$\frac{d\gamma_s}{d\theta}\bigg\vert_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2s}}=(-s\sin(s\frac{\pi}{2s}),s\cos(s\frac{\pi}{2s}))=(-s,0)=-s.$$
The issue is that on general manifolds we don't have a (canonical) embedding into $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we seek to find an alternative characterization to the tangent space. In the above, technically $s$ is a vector at $T_{(1,0)}S^1$ but I conflated this with a scalar using the isomorphism. Let us now not conflate the two.

To understand this alternative characterization, we first need to recall the whole point of wanting to have a notion of a tangent space in the first place. The idea is to capture velocity information as you travel through a point. But how do we practically use this velocity information? The answer is by taking directional derivative with respect to this velocity. Namely given *any* smooth function $f$, at a point $p$, we use velocity information $v$ by computing at $p$,
$$D f\cdot v=df(v)=vf.$$
I want to emphasize again that this is a pointwise calculation even though I'm suppressing the $p$ in the notation above (welcome to differential geometry). For example, if $v=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is from a coordinate system $x^1,...,x^n$, then we would be computing the standard partial derivatives, as
$$df(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}.$$
For concreteness, let us fix a smooth function $f(x,y):S^1\to \mathbb{R}$, say $f(x,y)=3xy$ as example. In this case, we compute
$$\frac{d(f\circ \gamma_s)}{d\theta}=\frac{df(\cos(s\theta),\sin(s\theta))}{d\theta}=\frac{d(3\cos(s\theta)\sin(s\theta))}{d\theta}=-3s\sin^2(s\theta)+3s\cos^2(s\theta).$$
Evaluating at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2s}$, we get
$$\frac{d(f\circ \gamma_s)}{d\theta}\bigg\vert_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2s}}=-3s.$$

Answer (score 0):

From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Tangent_vector_and_the_differential, a tangent vector can be defined as an equivalence class of curves passing through a point $p$ on the manifold while being tangent to each other at $p$.

From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Directional_differentiation, the directional derivative of a function $f$ at a point $p$ in a differentiable manifold, for a given tangent vector, is $\frac{d}{dt} [ (f \circ \gamma) (t) ]  \bigg\vert_{t=0} $ with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma$ a curve in the tangent vector’s equivalence class. So $f$ can be any differentiable function at $p$, meaning that $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is differentiable, where $\phi$ is a coordinate chart.

As an example, we could arbitrarily choose the following:

\begin{align*} 
\gamma(t) &=(-\sin t,\cos t), \\
f(p)      &= x, \\
\theta = \phi(p) &= - \arctan(x/y),\\
f \circ \phi^{-1}(\theta) &= -\sin \theta.
\end{align*}

We see that $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is differentiable. The tangent vector at $p$ is the equivalence class to which $\gamma(t)$ belongs. Note that the tangent vector is independent of the choices of $f$ or the coordinate chart $\phi$.

The directional derivative at the point $p=(0,1)=\gamma(0)$ is therefore

\begin{align*} 
\frac{d}{dt} [ (f \circ \gamma) (t) ]  \bigg\vert_{t=0} &= \frac{d}{dt}[ - \sin(t )]\bigg\vert_{t=0} \\
&= -1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you quoting the link?

Comment: @amWhy I'm closely summarizing the explanations in the Wikipedia links that I provided in the answer, adding some wording to clarify further because that helped me to understand it better. Would it be better practice to try to quote the wording exactly and use quotes around that?